# Merge rows from different tables using Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have 2 separate tables to store products. Although it is 2 different tables, their structure is exactly the same.

In these tables, each line has an item and the indication to which departments it should be made available.

However, because there are 2 tables, the same item can appear in the tables and in each one marking different departments.

I would like to make a table unifying the 2 previous ones and making sure that the item that appears repeated in the tables does not come out in 2 lines but that its line is merged, pointing in the new table the departments of the 2 tables.

Obviously this concept of departments is not real, I just used it to try to better explain my situation.

Please can you help me to resolve this?

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Table 01                              |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Product | Department A | Department B |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item A  | X            |              |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item B  |              | X            |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item C  |              | X            |
+---------+--------------+--------------+

+---------------------------------------+
| Table 02                              |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Product | Department A | Department B |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item A  |              | X            |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item C  | X            |              |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item D  | X            |              |
+---------+--------------+--------------+

+---------------------------------------+
| Merged tables                         |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Product | Department A | Department B |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item A  | X            | X            |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item B  |              | X            |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item C  | X            | X            |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Item D  | X            |              |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way in powwerquery, which has the benefit of working on any number of Department columns as you add more.  I assume you wanted to combine the text values with commas

```
let 
T1Source =  Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table1, {"Product"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
T2Source =  Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table2, {"Product"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
combined = Table.Combine({T1Source & T2Source}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(combined, {"Product", "Attribute"}, {{"data", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Value], Text.From), ","), type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "data")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

**ALTERNATE**

If there is never text in the same row/column intersection between tables, you could just use

```
let 
T1Source =  Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table1, {"Product"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
T2Source =  Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table2, {"Product"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
combined = Table.Combine({T1Source & T2Source}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(combined, List.Distinct(combined[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking for your ALTERNATE version. It was greate!